# Lazarus function to find 8 digit numbers in a string

Tags: lazarus

I have e-mail subject lines and I want to find ticket references in them it could be the TT ref is like 12345678. One subject line (string) can have multiple 8 digit numbers!

I have been using the below code but it is merely stripping out the <strike>first 8</strike> digits then doing a check if that is 8 char long:

```
function StripNumbers(const aString: string): string;
var
  C: char;
begin
  Result := '';
  for C in aString do
  begin
    if CharInSet(C, ['0'..'9']) then
    begin
      Result := Result + C;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Example:

my string variable is

```
subject := "yada yada XF12345678 blabla XF87654321 duh XF11.223344"
```

function `GetTTRefs(subject)` should result `"12345678;87654321;"`

Thank you for answers.

Comment: This code does not *strip out the first 8 digits*. It doesn't strip out anything, and it simply collects all of the digits from the string; it doesn't stop at 8, but will collect from zero to unlimited digits. You're going to need to be more clear what you're asking.

Comment: @ken-white i know it just strips all non digit chars from a string and i do a check afterward if that result is 8 digit long. i have added an example.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
function GotTTRefs(Subject:string;Digits:Byte):string;
var
  i:integer;
  TT:string;
begin
   i:=1;
   while i <= Length(Subject)-Digits+1 do
   begin
     if Subject[i] in ['1'..'9'] then
        begin
          TT:=Copy(Subject,i,Digits);
          if (StrToQWordDef(TT, 0) <> 0) then
              Result:=Result+TT+';';
        end;
     inc(i);
   end;
end;
```

Comment: That's pretty bad. You should iterate through the characters of the string, using array indexing `[i]` looking for values `>='0'` and `<='9'`. That way you don't need to perform any heap allocation until you find a value.

Comment: thanks David, I have now re-wrote this based on your suggestion.